# Error 403.14 when serving page from IIS

Tags: iis

This is very simple to reproduce:

1. Create a new VM (xtra small in my case, tried both Windows 2012
   and 2008R2)
2. Install IIS using default config.
3. Create a Web Site using IIS Manager specifying a folder such as
   C:\inetpub\simple.
4. Using Windows Explorer, create a new file called index.txt
5. Rename the file to index.htm
6. Edit the file with Notepad to make it a basic but valid html5
   document and Save.
7. From IIS Manager, select the new website and click the Browse
   Website link on the right side of the screen.

I get:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

Now look at the Contents of the web site in IIS Manager and you will see that the file has a .txt extension pasted onto the end : index.htm.txt

This does not happen on my local server.

I am new to Azure and probably missing something very basic but right now I feel like I am going insane. Can anyone put me out of my misery?

Answer (score 0):

This is IIS configuration issue, not Azure specific. And I would not even say it is an issue at all.

`index.html` is not in the list of default documents for IIS. And has never been. `index.htm` however is. You get 403.14 forbidden, because Directory Browsing is by default forbidden in IIS. Again, absolutely typical IIS configuration which hasn't changed for ages!

Your solutions:

- Configure index.html to be in default documents ([read how to do this here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753615%28v=ws.10%29.aspx))
- enable directory browsing ([read how to do it here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725840%28v=ws.10%29.aspx))

Comment: This is not the issue. Well, on my local server that IS true. However on Azure index.html is in the list of Default Documents. Anyway, to avoid confusion I just retried it using index.htm and same result. I have changed the example above to index.htm.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of others as stupid as me, this is all down to Windows Explorer configuration. Normally, the first thing that I do with a new Windows install is to turn off 'Hide known filename extensions'. This time I forgot.